# ¿Como puedo enviar datos de un controlador a otro en JavaFx?

Tags: javafx

Necesito enviar parámetros a los distintos controladores que utilizo, esto para mantener una cierta serie de validaciones con esta información, he logrado encontrar algunos ejemplos en internet, pero estos son demasiado inestables causando excepciones a montones y en algunas ocaciones es imposible utilizar la información que envío a los demás controladores. Este es el ejemplo que encontré pero quisiera saber si hay una manera mas factible de realizar lo que quiero:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Bien, nuevamente nadie en esta comunidad a podido resolver mi duda y he encontrado una solución por mi cuenta. Resulta que se generan problemas al utilizar métodos set almacenados en el segundo controlador ya que es imposible construir este objeto antes de utilizar dichos métodos (según algunos ejemplos encontrados en internet), la solución a todo esto es utilizar en el objeto "FXMLLoader" la función "load()" esto permitirá construir el segundo controlador y por consecuencia podremos hacer uso de sus métodos definidos "set" o cualquier otro tipo de método.
Aquí un ejemplo:

---

```
loader.setLocation(getClass().getResource("FXMLDocument.fxml"));
loader.load();
SegundoController document = loader.getController();
document.setEmployee(new Empleado(5,"Hola"));
Parent p = loader.getRoot();
Stage s = new Stage();
s.setScene(new Scene(p));
s.show();
```

Ahora desde el segundo controlador podremos hacer uso de la información recibida.